# What is Computer Trace and how do I unistall it?

Tags: uninstall

Can someone tell me what Computer Trace does and why it's installed on this computer, I went to BIOS and I saw it enabled, I would like to uninstall it I have no reason to have it installed on this computer. How to remove or uninstall computer trace on windows 10

Answer (score 0):

CompuTrace is firmware that is installed in a laptops's BIOS that allows it to be remotely tracked if stolen.

It is possible to remove it.  The steps may vary by manufacturer, but here is a [guide](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-access-the-bios-on-a-thinkcentre-computer) on how to do it that should work for most laptops.

Comment: Better link>>>https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-remove-computrace-from-bios

Comment: I have not seen Computrace in a long time. If the computer is properly secured, the data is safe anyway and the computer can be replaced.